# C# DataSet CheckBox Column With DevExpress DataGrid

Tags: c#, gridview, dataset, checkbox, devexpress

#### Scenario

I have a DevExpress DataGrid which is bound to a DataSet in C#.
I want to populate each dataset row to contain a string in the first column and a checkbox in the second. My code below doesn't work quite how I want it to, and I'm not sure why.....

#### The Code

As you can see I've declared a dataset, but when I try and pass in a new checkbox object to the 2nd column it just displays the system name for the checkbox.

```
        DataSet prodTypeDS = new Dataset();
        DataTable prodTypeDT = prodTypeDS.Tables.Add();
        prodTypeDT.Columns.Add("MurexID", typeof(string));
        prodTypeDT.Columns.Add("Haganise",typeof(CheckBox));

        //WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK? 
        //(Displays "System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox, CheckState: 0")
        //Instead of a checkbox.
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        prodTypeDS.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Test",c);
        //This doesn't work either....
        prodTypeDS.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Test",c.CheckState);
```

......I hope this is just because it's a DevExpress datagrid....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you use a `Checkbox` column in your `DataSet` ?

You should try adding a `bool` column in your `DataSet`, when binding the `DataSet` to the grid, it will automatically use a Checkbox to display the item value.

Comment: True, OP should use typeof(bool) column.

Answer (score 1):

When you dont have a bool column in your datatable you can also manually/in code set the editor for the column.

Example in code:
Say you add a devex grid column called "fCol".
The value for checked = "YES", unchecked = "NONO";

```
        GridColumn fCol = gridView1.Columns.Add();
        RepositoryItemCheckEdit fCheckEdit = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
        fCheckEdit.ValueChecked = "YES";
        fCheckEdit.ValueUnchecked = "NONO";
        fCol.ColumnEdit = fCheckEdit;
        fCol.FieldName = "Haganise";
```

Of course you can also do this in the designer.